# Pubnub GCM and Parse notifications not working together

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, pubnub

I'm working on app, using **Parse push notifications** and **Pubnub notification**. I need GCM registration id for **Pubnub**, so when I register gcm and get the reg_id and subscribe for **Pubnub channels**,  **Pubnub** starts working, but **Parse** stops working and when I use Parse's device token as Pubnub's reg_id then I don't receive Pubnub's notifications.

> String reg_id =
>   ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().getString("deviceToken");

With above reg_id I subscribe for pubnub notifications, I don't receive notifications on pubnub. I need both working together, how can I achieve this.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, any luck?

Comment: nope, I really don't understand, if deviceToken is actual gcm reg id then why its' not working!

Comment: I suspect the answer might be to configure parse to use the same sender id as pubnub and then only register one of them (parse)

Comment: We may need to dig a bit deeper into your apps (and get your account info/API keys to research this further), please shoot us emails at support@pubnub.com and we'll help you resolve this.

Comment: Just following up to see if you were able to resolve this and if you did indeed submit to support@pubnub.com.